# how to download Finite ELements tutorial as PDF

Tags: finite-element-method, documentation

For long tutorials, I prefer hard copy.

Is it possible to download from somewhere this document

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOverview.html

as PDF file?  Few years ago WRI used to have PDF files for all its documentations, but I am not able to find one for the above now.